# Ubuntu 20.04 croscompile using yocto jethro invalid gcc search paths

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, cross-compiling, yocto

I have been trying to cross-compile using toolchain from yocto-jethro BSP with the following error:

> x86_64-poky-linux-gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

I can see that the search directories have been truncated.
x86_64-poky-linux-gcc --print-search-dirs returns:

```
# /mnt/data/Projects/tmr2-sdk/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/x86_64-poky-linux/x86_64-poky-linux-gcc --print-search-dirs 

install: oots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/lib/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/5.2.0/
programs: =oots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/5.2.0/:oots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/5.2.0/:oots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/:oots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/lib/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/5.2.0/:oots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/lib/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/:oots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/x86_64-poky-linux/bin/x86_64-poky-linux/5.2.0/:oots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/x86_64-poky-linux/bin/
libraries: =oots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/lib/x86_64-poky-linux/gcc/x86_64-poky-linux/5.2.0/:oots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/x86_64-poky-linux/lib/../lib/x86_64-poky-linux/5.2.0/:oots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/x86_64-poky-linux/lib/x86_64-poky-linux/5.2.0/:oots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/x86_64-poky-linux/lib/../lib/:/not/exist/lib/../lib/x86_64-poky-linux/5.2.0/:/not/exist/lib/x86_64-poky-linux/5.2.0/:/not/exist/lib/../lib/:/not/exist/usr/lib/../lib/x86_64-poky-linux/5.2.0/:/not/exist/usr/lib/x86_64-poky-linux/5.2.0/:/not/exist/usr/lib/../lib/:oots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/x86_64-poky-linux/lib/:/not/exist/lib/:/not/exist/usr/lib/
```

Directories should start with:

```
 /mnt/data/Projects/tmr2-sdk/sdk/sysroots/
```

instead they start with:

```
 oots
```

I get the same result when I source the environment-setup-target from yocto BSP or execute compiler directly.

Cross-compilation was working on ubuntu 18. Similar BSP created in yocto-sumo works on ubuntu 20.04

When I add --sysroots to GCC it effects only the libraries search dirs.

Does anyone have a clue on how can I resolve the issue or where to look to find the problem?

Where does the gcc take the search-dirs? I can see that sourcing environment-setup-target does not effect the compiler search-dirs.

Thanks for any hints

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in later issues by commit:
https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/commit/scripts/relocate_sdk.py?id=c3c793b4286367b7050c8ec92fb90a1a9f85a89a